# Android Custom Tab Doesn't get right dimensions

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm creating a TabLayout with 5 tabs. I want to create a menu like the old Instagram. So for the 3rd tab , I need Custom View , So i will have different background color.
What i did until now is this :

```
 View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    view1.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_btn);


    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.home_btn));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tools_btn));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view1));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.countdown_btn));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.user_btn));
```

However I don't have the expected result . This is what I mean :
As you see , The background color i want , doesn't fill all the width of the specific tab.
[TabLayout Custom Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cFzu.png)

Custom_tab.xml file is using RelativeLayout , where I set the bg color ,  which in it has :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a default tablayout.setIcon() method, then you should use for all the tabs.

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view1));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view2));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view3));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view4));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab(.setCustomView(view5));
```

Then you will get right dimension for all tabs.

Comment: my friend i just did this , but i didn't get the expected result :/